# Customer name not appearing and products not showing in mini-cart, Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, cache, session, mini-cart

I have Magento 2.2.6 version. After signin, customer name is not showing on top dropdown bar, however if I reload the page aur goto another page it then appears.
Another issue is that when adding products to cart, first time the product is shown, after that if I add another product to cart then the mini cart shows "No products", however going to checkout/cart page, products appear there. It seems they are just not shown in mini-cart.
The issue appear to be in incognito mode. I have fpc enabled, and using varnish.

Comment: Does it show any interesting errors in the dev tools console?

Comment: There are, but I don't think they are related. Since the mini-cart works on first time and after that it doesn't show any products. But if I continue adding products then after 5-6 times it works automatically.
And for customer name issue, it also doesn't work on first time, but after I reload or move to another page, then the name begins to appear.
I think it is some cookie or sessions issue of Magento, but I am not getting it.
I have gone through:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5377 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6759
But none helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugged it. It was my theme issue. Upgraded the theme and it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue in the same 2.2.6 version, fixed it with this patch: 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/14973

If you open the link adding .patch to github's url you'll get it in a patch format: 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/14973.patch

Good luck!

Comment: Nope, not working! I found out that this issue is on chrome browser, not in firefox. In Firefox it is working with and without patch.

Comment: What you describe is the same behaviour we had, firefox never failed and chrome was quite random, after applying that patch it never happened again, is a pity that is not solving it for you

Comment: could you tell me how did you apply the patch? because I think the patch file with the link you provided is not complete! It shows the error corrupt patch, something like that. So I just copied the whole file from git repo (SessionManager.php) to my code

Comment: github patches dont really work straight away as they assume magento core is in app/code/Magento while normally is in vendor/magento, we built a custom system to apply magento patches using https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches and a custom script, I'm leaving you a copy of the patched file here: https://gist.github.com/santibm/37700c2d99564b0e4276ef8f075e3bf6

Comment: Can't I just copy and paste your file to my file in path vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php ?? because adding github patch seems to be quite complex.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I posted the file, just replace or declare a preference for your vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php with this one and try!

Comment: Sorry, not working with this also.